# Understanding reSize() and add() for Vector classes

Tags: java, vector, resize, addition

I am struggling with a java problem.

I am trying to understand how to assign value x to new elements added to a vector where the existing elements would remain unchanged, e.g. if it was resized from 3 to 5 then the 4th and 5th would have value x.

Additionally, in the next class I want to add another vector _v to the current vector. If this is bigger than the length of the current vector that reSize(int _size) is called. How do I write this?

```
public class Vector {
    private double[] doubElements;

    public Vector(double[] _elements) {
        this.doubElements = _elements;

    }

    public int getVectorSize() {

        return doubElements.length;
    }

    public Vector reSize(int _size) {
        if (_size == (doubElements.length - 1) || _size <= 0){
            return null;
        } else if (_size < (doubElements.length - 1)) {
            return new Vector(new double[]{doubElements[_size]});
        } else {
            return new Vector(new double[]{doubElements.add(-1.0)});
        }

    }

    public Vector add(Vector _v) {
        Vector.this.add(_v);
        if (getVectorSize(doubElements.length)) {
            reSize()...?
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you certain that you want `reSize` to return a new `Vector` rather than increasing the size of the current `Vector`? Likewise, what is `add` meant to do: add an element to the `Vector`, or return a new `Vector` which has elements equals to this vector with the new element appended?

Comment: Thanks for your response! I tried without new but that says it requires Vector to be a local variable/parameter. add is adding another vector, _v, to the current vector. It is running a premade test problem so has 4 different Vectors that are used in the test.

Comment: What resize should do is to create a new `double[]` of the correct size. It then needs to copy elements from `doubElements` into the new array, and finally assign the new array to `doubElements`. The resize method should have a `void` return type.

Comment: The `add` method needs to resize the vector to the current size plus the size of the vector being added, and then copy the elements of the vector being added to the appropriate elements of this vector.

Comment: Have a look at this array tutorial: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Comment: Thanks again! Unfortunately, the rules of the problem mean i cannot make the method a void return type. I am still confused on how to assign a value to new elements added to the vector while leaving current ones unchanged in the resize class.

Comment: Can you describe the semantics you want for `resize` (which is a method, not a class by the way) including what effect it should have on the Vector instance and what it's return value should be?

Comment: Here's the task I'm given:        If _size is smaller than the current length, only keep the first X elements
(X=_size). For example, resizing [1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0] to 3 should give you
[1.0,2.0,3.0].
– Otherwise, assign -1.0 to the new elements added to the vector but existing
elements remain unchanged. For example, resizing [1.0,2.0,3.0] to 5 should
give you [1.0,2.0,3.0,-1.0,-1.0];

Comment: I think that array tutorial tells you everything you need to know to do that. I still don't understand what resize should return.

Comment: It should return a new vector with the specified size/length. I'm unsure on how to assign -1.0 to the new elements added

Comment: Leaving the existing Vector unchanged? To assign the value -1.0 to an element of an array you use `theArray[index] = -1.0;`

Comment: Sorry new in the sense that the vector is modified if _size does not equal the current vector length.  I am unable to write that without error

Comment: I think that array tutorial, and perhaps a few more basic Java tutorials would be helpful.

Comment: Consider returning `this` if you need to return the existing Vector and keeping it exactly as it is.